# Is it possible to replace text by other text in SqlBase?

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

Is it possible to replace text in a SqlBase? I found there is a @REPLACE function but I see it just replaces using positions in the string:

**The following expression returns the value 'RALPH':**

```
@REPLACE('RALF', 3, 1, 'PH')
```

What I need is to replace a substring by another, In Sql Server it's like this:

**This returns 'ABA':**

```
SELECT REPLACE('ABC', 'C', 'A')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the literals in your 'ABC' to 'ABA' example....

```
Select @REPLACE( 'ABC', @FIND( 'C', 'ABC', 0 ), @LENGTH('C'),  'A' )
```

Using the literals in your 'RALF' to 'RALPH' example....

```
Select @REPLACE( 'RALF', @FIND( 'F', 'RALF', 0 ), @LENGTH('F'),  'PH' )
```

Comment: Obviously you can replace literals with column names